# How can i expand root online?

Tags: partition

I want to have a more space on root(sda7), and I finally search to find that using `resize2fs /dev/sda7` can help, but I'm not quite sure. Is it better to resize it by live-cd.

Can anyone advice me on this steps by steps?
Thanks in advances!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to resize partition on /?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/is-it-safe-to-resize-partition-on). Also, typing `resize2fs` in google yields step-by-step options as soon as of second result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I do not believe resize2fs will work without serious games, as it assumes that the start does not move. there may be other tools that do not have this restriction, but they will definitely have to be done with the target unmounted (live cd or the like). A traditional solution would be to add another partition in the gap, format it and move stuff at a file system level (maybe use it as /var).

If you are set on resizing the partition It can be done by hand. **Here there be dragons!**

- do a backup and verify it works.
- have your head examined for trying something so dangerous.
- boot from a live cd.
- do not mount the file system.
- run fsck.
- write down the start and end blocks of the gap and the partition you are modifying.
- edit the partition table without moving any data to have the same end block as the old partition and the earliest start block you can fit in the gap.
- use dd to copy the first 2.88 gb from the beginning of the file system to the beginning of the partition.
- repeat with the next 2.88gb.
- repeat until finished using a smaller size for last copy.
- run fsck.
- run resize2fs.
- run fsck.
- check bootloader. It may need to be reinstalled.
- reboot and pray it works.

Answer (score 1):

`resize2fs` is a tool used to resize the filesystem, not the underlying block device. Before you can use `resize2fs`, you need to ensure that the underlying device (`/dev/sda7` in this case) has more space available to use. In normal usage, the filesystem is sized correctly for its underlying device; thus, usually, you need to grow the block device before you can grow the filesystem.

Since you're using bare OS partitions here, this is a somewhat complicated endeavor. The best available option is likely to reboot into a liveCD and use `gparted`, as your screenshot shows. (Resizing partitions on your root drive of the running system is possible, but fraught.) To grow a partition, you need space to grow it into, either space on the same disk that's already free, or space freed by shrinking another partition. `gparted` is the best available tool for this; it will automatically convert a request for resizing into the requisite FS-shrink, partition-shrink, move, partition-grow, FS-grow operations. In fact, since `gparted` handles its own FS operations, you don't even need to run `resize2fs` manually. Note that doing this may well take a long time; moving a partition involves block-by-block copying all its data from place to place.

If you plan to do this kind of thing regularly, you may be well-advised to switch to LVM. But that's a separate discussion.